# how to replace a specific word into another word in R

Tags: r

Im looking for the code in gsub to replace a specific word into xx like this.

`x <- c("replace #bitcoin and not #bitoinusdha", "replace #btc and not #btcasdasd")`

```
View(x)
[1] replace  xx and not #bitcoinusdha
[2] replace xx and not #btcasdasd
```

Hope that someone can help me out.

Regards,

Otto

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that the phrases to replace always start with `#abc...`, then use use a word boundary at the end of each pattern and search for either value.

```r
x <- c("replace #bitcoin and not #bitcoinusdha", "replace #btc and not #btcasdasd")
gsub("#bitcoin\\b|#btc\\b", "xx", x)
#> [1] "replace xx and not #bitcoinusdha" "replace xx and not #btcasdasd"
```